# Is it possible to connect NRF24L01 to localhost in laptop without wifi router?

Tags: wifi, nrf24l01+, python

I want to send data from arduino to my localhost port:8080(with ipython notebook) via modul NRF24L01 without WiFi router. Is it possible? If it possible, how to do that?
Thank  you...

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have 2 NRF24L01 radios to talk to each other without a WIFI router.

However, is it possible to get your notebook to talk to a NRF24L01?  Probably not unless you can write a device driver for it.

You could use two Arduinos each with a NRF24L01, and get one to receive the data and then send it via Serial to you laptop, but you would be better looking at an ESP8266, set that up as an access point, connect your laptop to that network and job done.

(By the way you won't be able to call you laptop localhost)